# how to securely send topic notifications based on app user action

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have groups system which allows users to join groups. I need to send notifications to other users when new members join/leave the group.

I don't have any server-side code. I only depend on the Firebase. After reading Firebase docs about firebase could messaging I found it's possible to send a notification message to a specific topic by sending a single HTTP request. but that request must include Authentication key like this

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : /topics/foo-bar",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message",
  }
}
```

*So I am asking is it secure to place the authentication key in IOS App code? Is there any better way to implement device-to-devices notifications without exposing the authentication key?*

Comment: You can always use Keychain services to securely store and retrieve the authentication key in iOS. Here's a link for tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/147308/secure-ios-user-data-keychain-touch-id

Comment: @KrishnaCA sure, this's the only road i can think about, but i thought maybe there is a better way to implement that